# Using python BeautifulSoup and Selenium, how to append ID back to the main content so Selenium can find the element?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Let's say I have some html without an `id`, but with a `data-custom-id` that is unique.

```
<a href="#abc" data-custom-id="m123">
<a href="#def" data-custom-id="m456">
<a href="#ghi" data-custom-id="m789">
```

I can use beautiful soup to find all of these elements in a larger HTML string

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")  # or lxml 
links = soup.find_all('a', {"data-id": True, "href": True})
for link in links:
    link_id = (1 + links.index(link))
    link.attrs['id'] = "mylink-" + str(link_id)
```

Notice, I can even append an "id" attribute with `attrs`, but I want to be able to access this attribute with selenium, which does not work.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5]")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--verbose")


chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
# chrome_options.headless = True # also works

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe') # version 89

for i in range(1, (link_id + 1)):
    mylink_id = "mylink-" + str(link_id)
    driver.find_element_by_id(mylink_id).click()
```

I am guessing that `append` is only appending to the local string, not back to the main `html`.

As a result, `selenium` CANNOT find it and click on it.

Part of the error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Python is not my forte, so it may be something easy that I am missing.

I am not opposed to using `lxml` as the parser, nor am I opposed to using `xpath` or some other selenium find path.  (Maybe there is a data-custom-id method that I don't see in the DOCS)

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#locate-elements-by

Comment: You can use XPATH, e.g., `//a[@data-custom-id='m456']`

Comment: Is there an actual url to work with? And why wouldn't a css attribute=value selector find the required elements in the html?